# Python MySQLdb: Iterating over a cursor

Tags: python, iterator, mysql-python

In another post, this code:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
for (table_name,) in cursor:
    print(table_name)
```

correctly iterates over the table names in the cursor whereas this code:

```
for table_name in cursor:
    print(table_name)
```

returns elements in the form:

```
('some_table',)
```

After much searching, I have been unable to make sense of this.  Could someone explain the difference?  I cannot figure out exactly what execute() is returning.  Also, I cannot figure out why the form of the first iterator -- using parentheses and a comma -- works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In itself, `execute()` doesn't return anything.  Once you've executed a query, you get the data back from the query as tuples when you iterate over the cursor.

Your query returns only one column, so you get 1-tuples.

1-tuples in Python look a bit odd.  `()` is an empty tuple, and `(1, 2)` is a 2-tuple, but `(1)` is just the digit `1` in parentheses, not a tuple.  1-tuples such as `(1,)` must therefore have the trailing comma in order to be recognised as tuples.

If you ran a query that selected three columns, you could read the three values out from each row using something like the following:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT a, b, c FROM some_table")
for (a_value, b_value, c_value) in cursor:
    # do stuff...
```

Your first code is doing the same, but it's unpacking 1-tuples instead of 3-tuples.

On the other hand, your second code is simply iterating over what comes out of the cursor, i.e. the 1-tuples, without doing any unpacking.

Comment: Many thanks.  I thought the output looked like tuple "fragments" because of the trailing comma.  I haven't coded in Python for a long time and I forgot about the format of 1-tuples.