# How to iterate through cursor after mysql select * query in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am querying all the fields of a mysql table like this -

```
query = """select * from %s where %s=%s;""" % (tableName,key,value)
cursor.execute(query)
```

Now, I would like to iterate over the results. I do not want to specify the column names which I would like to fetch as I would like to fetch all. This is part of a generic migration verification script which is supposed to do the verification for all the mysql tables. Since there will be different number of columns in different tables, I would like a general solution.

I checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/25347195/351903 but it involves specific fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQLdb conforms to [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Therefore,`execute` must return an iterator. You can just do:

```
for tupl in cursor.execute(query):
    pass
```

where `tupl` is a tuple.

---

*Alternatively, you can use `fetchone`, `fetchmany(n)` or `fetchall()` to evaluate at once.

Comment: Yes it works. I did some wrong observation it seems.

Answer (score 0):

First run below query

```
sp_help Table
```

then get the column names from that

after that run your code. Because you will have column names.

I also created this type of utility. That was windows console app.